# Zeroes of Transfer Functions

Tags: laplace-transform

The question is:

Show that $s(s^2 + 5s + 4) + k$ has only zeros with negative real part, provided
that, $k < 20 $.

I know that both roots of $s^2 + as + b$ have negative real part if, and only if, a and b are
both positive. How would I apply it to  a 3rd degree polynomial?

I am fairly certain that you are mean to assume k is positive and that you need to use the idea of closed-loop tranfer functions.

Comment: Nickalls' paper on the geometric solution to the cubic should help.  http://nickalls.org/dick/papers/maths/cubic1993.pdf

Comment: This is clearly false if $k$ is negative: the parenthetical piece is 0 at $s=0$, positive for $s>0$ and will go to infinity for large $s$, so you'll have a real zero with positive real part. Please check your conditions on $k$.

Comment: Normally $k$ is real positive for these problems...

Comment: This should be related in some way to the root locus for a direct feed system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we are looking at:

$$\text{s}\cdot\left(\text{s}^2+5\cdot\text{s}+4\right)+\text{k}=0\tag1$$

Now, eliminate the quadratic term by substituting $x:=\text{s}+\frac{5}{\text{s}}$, then we end up with:

$$\frac{70}{27}+\text{k}-\frac{13}{3}\cdot x+x^3=0\tag2$$

Change coordinates by substituting $x=\text{y}+\frac{\lambda}{\text{y}}$, where $\lambda$ is a constant value that will be determined later and after that let $\lambda=\frac{13}{9}$ and let $\text{z}:=\text{y}^3$, then we end up with:

$$\frac{2197}{729}+\frac{\text{z}\cdot\left(70+27\cdot\text{k}\right)}{27}+\text{z}^2=0\tag3$$

Which is a quadratic equation in $\text{z}$, so I think you can solve it from here.